# How to find how much data Spark keeps in memory and on disk of a RDD or Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark

After caching a data frame. How can we calculate how much data is kept in memory and how much in disk.

Any data frame tried to cache

source_df.cache()

Answer (score 2):

In the spark UI there is a Tab "Storage". This will show you the info you need.
Here is a screenshot from another question ([Spark Structured Streaming - UI Storage Memory value growing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56439881/spark-structured-streaming-ui-storage-memory-value-growing)):

[image: Storage Tab of Spark UI]

More infos in the spark UI can be found in the docs https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html

Comment: I don't want to monitor from UI. i want calculate after creating a RDD or Dataframe. Is there any way to get those informations. After doing some search i saw we can use getRDDStorageInfo().

Comment: Need help on .how to use getRDDStorageInfo() function

Comment: just use `sc.getRDDStorageInfo` where sc is your active SparkContext. This will give you an array of `RDDInfo`s. An RDD info has  diskSize and memSize attributes. Full docs here (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.storage.RDDInfo). Do you need more than that?

Comment: how can I use this with pyspark tho

Comment: struggling to get the syntax right (I've been working with PySpark for 4 years so not your average newbie)